# Store the word found in a array as a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, environment-variables, discord.js

```
let a = process.env.a
   for(let word of a){
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)){
      var vs = //The Word Found In A Discord Message
      message.reply("Said " + "'" + vs + "'")
      break;
      }
  }
```

How do I store the word found in the discord message as VS

Comment: Umm... Doesn't `word` contain the word you're looking for? This is where using the debugger built into your browser is a good idea.

Comment: Its nodejs... I can't really debug like that.

Comment: @LockdownGaming [yes you can](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/debugger.html#debugger_advanced_usage)

Comment: Please include an example of `process.env.a` and `message.content`, since apparently `word` does not actually contain the word you're looking for.

Comment: message.content is the message from the discord server and process.env.a is ['badword1', 'badword2']

Answer (score 0):

`word` contains the word you're looking for, so send that instead of using another variable.

Comment: It only gives me the first letter of it for some reason.

Comment: Can you show what do you have in process.env.a

Comment: Example: ['badword1', 'badword2']

Comment: I doubt `process.env.a` has an array, it's probably a string.

Comment: It looks like the example above.

Comment: @LockdownGaming it could very well be the string `"['badword1', 'badword2']"` and not the array `['badword1', 'badword2']`. Environment variables are usually just string types.

Comment: @LockdownGaming Please [edit] your question to include more information. Comments are frequently deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `word` variable stores the value you need.

If you meant, that you need to find some variable with specific characteristics, you can use examples below.

- This code finds the first element of array that has length more than 2 (not equal):

```
    const arr = ['aa', 'bbb', 'cccc'];

    const word = arr.find(elem => elem.length > 2);
```

- This code finds the first object in array `persons` that has `age` variable more than 18 (not equal).

```
    const persons = [
      {
        name: 'Alex',
        age: 18
      },
      {
        name: 'Sardor',
        age: 20
      }
    ];
  
    const word = persons.find(person => person.age > 18);
```

Read more about [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Also check out [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)